# Items order in flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build media query, which will be working like on the sketch. Any suggestion?[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.name {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
  flex-basis: 40px
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.option {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
  flex-basis: 80px;
}

.action {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
}

@media (max-width: 350px){
  .name     {order: 1}  
  .action   {order: 2}
  .options  {order: 3}

  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="name">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="option">2</div>
      <div class="option">3</div>
      <div class="option">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have already started, but I'm not really satisfied :). I need something more stable, as I will want to use it here later.

```
https://codepen.io/danzawadzki/pen/mwPYMz
```

At this moment I'm changing order and flex-direction in media query, but it's not good enough. Box number 1 will contain name of the segment, so it should have fixed width. There will be multiple items like that in one column, so I would prefer to keep it looks clean with same proportions.

Comment: Based on what you mean with _There will be multiple items like that in one column_, if that is not part of your question we can't provide a proper answer

Comment: May I ask if you down voted my answer?

Comment: @LGSon ofc, that no! Thanks a lot for your time and answer :). Now i see i didnt explain exacly what i want. You have solved my problem party :).

Comment: I didn't thought so, so thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `@media` and remove `flex-direction: column` and add `flex-basis: 100%` to the `option`, it will flow as your image shows

```
@media (max-width: 350px){
  .options  {
    order: 1; flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

*Note, I also removed the `.name` and `.action` rules, as they are not necessary*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pagv1kqt/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.name {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
  flex-basis: 40px
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.option {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
  flex-basis: 80px;
}

.action {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
}

@media (max-width: 350px){
  .options  {
    order: 1; flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="option">2</div>
      <div class="option">3</div>
      <div class="option">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

*Updated*

*By setting `.options { flex-grow: 1; }` and `.option { flex: 1 1 80px; }`, you can have the `options`/`option` elements to fill the remaining space on wider screens*

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/pagv1kqt/2/)

Stack snippet 2

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.name {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
  flex-basis: 40px
}

.options {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.option {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
  flex: 1 1 80px;
}

.action {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .25rem;
}

@media (max-width: 350px){
  .options  {
    order: 1; flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="option">2</div>
      <div class="option">3</div>
      <div class="option">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Down voter, please comment so I can clarify any mistake or misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Use this may be it will work for you

```
@media (max-width: 350px){
  .options  {order: 3; flex:0 0 100%;}
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```